# My site isn't loading properly in FireFox

Tags: html, xhtml, css

My site works great in IE and Chrome, its messed up in Firefox though...

When I turn on Firebug, and click on HTML it suddenly becomes view-able how it should be, what would cause this??

http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/solera_new/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This css will fix your issues on firefox and chrome but I'm not sure your site will work on all other browsers, trouble will follow when you still you use table to design your menu, and apply css "possition: absolute" for td tag. Let try to remove all and use list tags.

```
td.imageholder {
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height:120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure since I'm limited in the testing I can do, but the error you get in firefox is:

`P7_initHGM is not defined`

I looked at your head tag and it looks like the `p7pmm/p7PMMscripts.js` script is being called twice. Maybe if you got rid of one that would help fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see is that a font is trying to load and fails, and you have a function that is being called from Javascript (P7_initHGM) that is causing an error which may be causing a lag in the rendering of the site. Beyond that I would put all of the javascript down at the bottom of the page and see if that makes the render different.

Answer (score 0):

This is not HTML5 and is using XHTML1.1 DTD. If you want to statically position an element you should do it outside of a table and inside a div. If you want to create more standards compliant, convert everything to a DIV (tableless) layout. This will cure it without having the needs to try to reposition everything. Warning: Even if you do follow @pacificvn answer, it may not work in some older browsers like IE 7/8 which about 60% of internet users still use. And you are using Chrome Tab for IE which is an addon that not everyone will install.

When checking your code for W3C Validaty it shows that your tag element for the imageholder is not properly wrapped in the table. http://validator.w3.org/unicorn/check?ucn_uri=graves-incorporated.com%2Ftest_sites%2Fsolera_new%2Findex.html&ucn_task=conformance#

I would suggest for you to look at this reference on tabless design: http://www.w3.org/2002/03/csslayout-howto (not the best but it is a start - google search div tabless design)

As far as web development these will get you far if you can develop a page that meets standards and is using more upto date coding standards. Websites can be made to look good with tables, but are limited. I have converted many sites from table design to tableless.

Note: IE Usage is based on the analytics of about 30 sites that I currently have built or maintained.